# how to add key val to each element of array in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

suppose I have this structure:

```
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5c87cbf35ed912737d097301"),
        "el" : [ 
            {
                "a" : "b"
            }, 
            {
                "a" : "b"
            }, 
            {
                "a" : "b"
            }, 
            {
                "a" : "b"
            }
        ]
    }
```

How do I add to each element of el  {x:1}?

Comment: By "add" you mean add in query or update all elements in db ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update your database you need [$ positional all operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/#up._S_[])

```
db.col.update({ "_id" : ObjectId("5c87cbf35ed912737d097301") }, { $set: { "el.$[].x": 1 } })
```

To add this value when querying you need [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/index.html) and [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html)

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            el: {
                $map: {
                    input: "$el",
                    in: {
                        a: "$$this.a",
                        x: 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: the update query you wrote  is exactly what I was trying to do, but i get "cannot use part to traverse element"

Comment: @sathia what MongoDB version ?

Comment: mongo:3.2.11, maybe it's that the reason?

Comment: Yes, this operator was introduced in `3.6`. Any possibilites of upgrading ?

Comment: I'll look into it, i'm testing against a prod server. thank you very much for your help

Comment: @sathia I can try to figure out some workaround for lower versions if needed, you can take a look at $out operator it might be helpful for lower versions

Comment: that would be very helpful from the learning point of view, however I think we need to upgrade now, so I'll also be looking into that. thanks again